# How to reference 3rd party library in c++ text editor?

Tags: c++, text-editor

For example purposes lets assume I was using regular notepad. How would I reference a 3rd party library I downloaded so that I would be able to access its header files? This is probably a really easy thing to do. Can someone explain it to me please? I am using a text editor similar to joes text editor. Here is some example code I wrote using the sfml library for c++. I don't know how to get the text editor to know where the header files for sfml are.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm suspicious that this is not the actual question that you are looking to ask since, as it stands, it's sort of a nonsense question.

Comment: @Ike does this answer your real question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868808

Comment: Some prodding revealed what I believe to be the real question.  I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your *regular notepad* text editor doesn't know and doesn't need to know where other files are.

When you **compile** your code, you will **tell the compiler** where those files are.

Different compilers have different ways of being told this.

Comment: or use a plugin for your editor that might find those files on the run. but that's another story.

Comment: are you familiar with how to do this with mingw g++?