# Fatal Error Message during Compiling

Tags: c, cygwin

Trying to compile a c file that has the header:

`#include <sys/wait.h>`

I'm using Cygwin to compile it and it keeps giving me this error whenever I type in `gcc minishell.c -o minishell`:

`minishell.c:4:22: fatal error: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

Any clue what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because compiler, in this case, does not know how to reach/find `sys/wait.h` file so that it can include this file in compilation process. To check which all places compiler will try to find the files, refer:
[How to tell C++ library path in Cygwin and MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868808/how-to-tell-c-library-path-in-cygwin-and-mingw)

Above post/link also tells about include paths.

Comment: Compiling with `-v` option will give information about include directories which are looked up.